# Display Summary Result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table structure also I have mention my expected output please help me with query as I don't know much about SQL query

**Table 1 : Category**

```
Name      CatId   
 A         1   
 B         2   
 C         3
```

**Table 2 : Emp Details**

```
FName      Id   Dob           CatId
Pratik      1   1958-04-06      2
Praveen     3   1972-05-12      1 
Nilesh      2   1990-12-12      2
```

So far I have tried to get all result with:

```
SELECT A.Code,A.EmpName,A.DOB,B.cname 
FROM EMPMASTER A
JOIN CATMASTER B ON A.cCode = B.ccode AND A.Compcode = B.CompCode
WHERE A.compcode = 'C0001' AND  month(A.DOB) >= 1 
      AND MONTH(A.DOB) <= 12  AND A.termflag='L' 
ORDER BY  A.DOB
```

But my problem is, I also want summary results to be displayed

**Expected Summary Output :**

```
Grouping           No Of Employees
 A                     1
 B                     2
 C                     0
```

Comment: In future if you ask a SQL question with SQL code, add the SQL tags first (rather than c#). This way syntax highlighting will be SQL specific rather than C# specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` as follows:

```
SELECT  [Grouping] = c.Name,
        [No Of Employees] = COUNT(e.ID)
FROM    Category AS c
        LEFT JOIN EmpDetails AS e
            ON e.CatId = c.CatId   
GROUP BY c.Name;
```

Comment: Kindly dont use `=` for Alias

Comment: @Rajesh Why not? In my opinion it is the most clear way of using column aliases. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) pretty much sums up my opinions on the matter, and quite frankly, there is very little that Aaron Bertrand has written that I disagree with....

Comment: After reading the article by Aaron Bertrand I specified not to use `=` as alias,kindly specify why you disagree with that article in here or in chat

Comment: Exactly, I do not disagree with the article. I completely agree with it. [This image](http://bertrandaaron.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/bh_as_procs.png) sums it up, I find it much easier to scan down the select list and see the column aliases aligned, rather than trying to find the end of the expression to locate the column alias. It is ultimately personal preference, and my preference is for `Alias = <Expression>`

Comment: Okay agreed with your point and also one Comment in that article specified its been used for good Fine Tuning is it True?

Comment: There is no mention of tuning in the article, but no, this notation has absolution no effect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS:

```
 SELECT A.NAME, 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #EMP B WHERE A.CATID = B.CATID) AS COUNT  
 FROM #TEMP A
```